# Tackling a slightly modified sum identity involving binomials

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Summing binomials with alternating signs is known in [certain cases, for instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Partial_sums):
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^j\binom nj=0 \tag{1}
$$
I am trying to show that when the prefactor of the binomial is divided by a first order polynomial of type $j+1$, the sum becomes $\frac{1}{1+n}$. In other words, that

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^j\binom nj}{j+1}=\frac{1}{1+n} \tag{2}
$$
I've tried first tackling the case of $j$ instead of $j+1$ in the denom., but it didn't lead to anything simpler than the current problem. Any ideas for how to make progress showing such identity would be much appreciated, or referring to similar problems that are solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class of techniques - which I love - is called generating functions.
The idea is that some algebraic manipulations on series and polynomials translate some non-intuitive operations on a sequence. In this case you know the summation of a sequence, and you want to know what's the summation of the sequence with a $1/(j+1)$ in front of. You will see this principle in action in a while.

Consider the polynomial

$$p(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{x^{j+1}}{j+1} \binom{n}{j} $$

Note that $x^{j+1}/(j+1)$ is the antiderivative of $x^j$, so that

$$ p(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n \int x^j \binom{n}{j} = \int \sum_{j=0}^n x^j \binom{n}{j} = \int (1+x)^n = \frac{(1+x)^{n+1} -1}{n+1} $$

The $-1$ pops up to match the constant term ($p(0) = 0$). Now note that when we evaluate $p(x)$ in $-1$ we almost get our result; indeed

$$ -p(-1) = -\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j+1} \binom{n}{j} = \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(-1)^j}{j+1}\binom{n}{j} $$

is what we are looking for. Using the antiderivative like manipulation we get that

$$ -p(-1) = -\frac{ (1-1)^{n+1}-1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}$$

As desired.

Comment: Thanks very much, this has been very instructive.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The relation

$$\frac1{j+1}\binom nj=\frac1{n+1}\binom{n+1}{j+1}$$ will turn your second identity to the first.